# Sci-fi short stories where the title had the word "box" in it

Tags: story-identification

This book contained short Sci-fi stories. I think the author was female. 
It was small, paperback, and had a colour illustration of young, blonde girl holding a light globe or orb under her chin.

Comment: Oh wow, there's very little to go off here. Where and when did you read it? Also, please check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Sometimes that is all you need :P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short Story of a Boy with an Invisible Box that Contains Joy/Happiness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266463/short-story-of-a-boy-with-an-invisible-box-that-contains-joy-happiness) - newer question+answer contains a lot more info

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is *The Anything Box* by Zenna Henderson.

[image: US paperback cover of The Anything Box]

Comment: Yes !  That's it; The Anything Box !  THANK YOU !!!!!!!

Comment: Sadly out of print, but you should be able to find a used copy at ABEbooks or someplace similar. If you don't mind, please check that this answers your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I've never been here before. I hope I checked everything off.

Comment: Thank you so, so much !  ABEbooks has it.

Comment: @mkennedy how did you even find it with so little info? Great job!

Comment: I wasn't aware of isfdb. Shame on me for being on scifi stackexchange and not knowing it lol.

Comment: "She" has the book and considers Henderson a favorite author. Given the info from Tatiana I immediately flashed on the book. I don't often get to answer a question here!

Comment: I tried to be as descriptive and detailed as possible. It was swiped from me 35 years ago? I guess I filled out the boxes all wrong. But, today was mylucky day ! 

Comment: Read the question, thought "I wonder if they can answer this. I'm curious myself now." Read the answer, thought "Oh right! The Anything Box!"